# layout not proper in small screen laptop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

- the layout is fine for 24 inch laptop...
  where as when i see it in 11 inch laptop the layout is not proper...
  the right column breaks down and moves downwards....

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/92/embedded/result/

providing my code below

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 325px;">
    <div class="span12 pagination-centered" style="font-style: arial; font-size: 21px; color: #cc0000; margin-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 113px;">
            Main Menu
    </div>
    <div class="span5" style="margin-left: 97px; width: 493px;">
        <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/search.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/yourfiles.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/shareFiles.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/custProfile.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/custQuote.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/salesOrders.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/vendorProfile.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/reports.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/yourfiles.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/admin.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/shipLogistic.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/accReceivable.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/custRMA.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/production.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/CRM.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span5" style="margin-left: 65px; width: 493px;">
        <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/accPayable.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/vendorRMA.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/manuPlanning.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/productLifeCycle.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/multiMedia.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/receiving.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/tax.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/admin.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/ISOprocess.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/intergration.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/comDocuments.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="/images/cubes/TBU4.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="/images/cubes/TBU5.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="/images/cubes/TBU5.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="/images/cubes/TBU5.png"></div>
            <div data-caption="" data-image="/images/cubes/TBU5.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on an application where it has to work on a computer screen, laptop screen and mobile screen. Best thing to do is change your size from pixels to percentages. With percentages it resizes things by percentage of the screen, with pixels it just counts pixels, so if screen is smaller, then total size of pixels are smaller and hence you are struggling resizing elements

Look at it this way for example:

**PIXELS:**

400 pixels of 900 pixels screen equals 400 pixels (500 pixels remaining)

400 pixels of 1200 pixels screen equals 400 pixels (800 pixels remaining)

**PERCENTAGE:**

25% of 800 pixels screen is 200 pixels (exactly quarter of screen)

25% of 1200 pixels screen is 300 pixels (exactly quarter of screen)

Hope you understand :)

Comment: @js.js All I am saying is change the pixels to a relevant percentage, you will have to mess about until you get it to what you want, there is too much code in your fiddle. But just change pixels to relevant percentage such as 18px change to make it 2%. You have to mess about with it so you get same width and height when using percentage rathr than pixels

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider doing something responsive with a layout like this. Either by using a plug-in like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or a responsive framework like [foundations](http://foundation.zurb.com/).